# How to replace bookmarks in PDF with java and save the PDF that replaced the bookmark as TXT?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I want to be able to replace bookmarks (contents) in PDF documents, such as "1. Start" to "< 1. Start >", and save the replaced PDF into TXT files.

I used the pdfbox Library of Java to complete the transformation from PDF to txt. Then, I completed the extraction of bookmarks (contents) and saved all bookmarks with String, which was successfully written to the TXT file. But after I converted the bookmark (contents), I could not successfully save the PDF that converted the bookmark.

```java
    // Used to save bookmark strings
    private static String res = "";
    // Recursive calls to get bookmark
    private static void printBookmark(PDOutlineNode bookmark, int indentation) throws IOException {
        PDOutlineItem current = bookmark.getFirstChild();
        while (current != null) {
            res += "<" + indentation + ">" + current.getTitle() + "\n";
            // Can I add some code here to change the bookmark of the loaded PDDocument?
            // I tried to define temp_current, temp_bookmark to store the desired value and 
            // finally assign it to the PDDocument object, but it failed.
            printBookmark(current, indentation + 1);
            current = current.getNextSibling();
        }
    }
```

Any changes to my bookmarks did not affect the files I saved from PDF to txt.

Comment: Do you mean a table of contents on a page, or the bookmarks (outlines) that Adobe shows on the left? If the later, you can change them with `PDOutlineItem.setTitle()`.

Comment: Yes, I tried "current.setTitle ("<"+indentation+">"+current.getTitle()+"\\n")"with its changes; but I didn't know how to save the changes to pdf, so I could not convert the changed PDF to TXT.

Comment: I just tried and it works, the outlines are changed. You need to save the file with document.save(). But be aware that a table of contents on a page is unrelated. That is just text. It will not change "automatically". https://imgur.com/a/RvAxiRk

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me try first.

Comment: How do you create the TXT file?

Comment: PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream(output)));
            stripper.writeText(pd, wr);

Comment: PDFTextStripper works on the pages, not on the outlines. The text on the page has no relation to the text in the outlines. Changing a text is very, very, very difficult, read [Why was the ReplaceText example removed?](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html#why-was-the-replacetext-example-removed)

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.